# Anomalous precession of the orbit of Mercury

Tags: general-relativity, orbital-motion, planets, solar-system, precession

Can the anomalous precession of the orbit of Mercury be explained just with relativistic length contraction?

Comment: No. If it could we wouldn't need general relativity to explain it.

Comment: @JohnRennie That sounds like a good answer.

Comment: @G.Smith possibly a bit brief for an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

No. Before Einstein came up with General Relativity, physicists tried various special-relativistic generalizations of Newtonian gravity. They didn’t work, and no one has found one since that works.

By contrast, General Relativity can explain not just the anomalous precession of Mercury, but everything else we have observed about gravity.

Comment: I would be interested in references to such attempts.

Comment: @my2cts In the section “Lorentz-invariant models (1905-1910)”, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternatives_to_general_relativity mentions failed attempts by Poincaré, Minkowski, and Sommerfeld.

Comment: Well, not "everything". There are UV (big bang/black hole singularity) and IR (cosmological constant) problems still.

Comment: @Avantgarde I said “observed”. We haven’t observed gravity’s UV regime, and a cosmological constant (but not an explanation of it) is part of GR. $\Lambda$ is in some sense *more* basic than $G$ because it simply is the coefficient of the zero-order-of-curvature term in the gravitational action.

Comment: @G.Smith Yes, but $\Lambda$ is just one way. There are other infrared modifications of gravity too, like ghost condensation, non-local gravity, etc.

Comment: @Avantgarde Is there any observational evidence yet that requires such modifications of GR to explain it? If so, can you provide a reference? Thanks!

Comment: @G.Smith Our accelerating universe is the evidence. I mean $\Lambda$ is one, but there are other possible explanations too, which form an active field of research. Unfortunately, I'm not well-versed with how the experimental data fits with all these different models, so I can't choose one more over the others. Anyway, here's a nice review (there are other reviews you can easily find): https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.0059